# What is the proper way to deploy a rails website (blog) on my home server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, webserver

domainname.com points to my router's external ip address.
router port 80 is open and directs to my server internal ip address.
using mamp, the server opens the content in the folder "htdocs"

How worried should I be for the security of my system running a private web blog with these settings?

How can I get my rails web app to run? ie how can I deploy my rails website on my home server?
I tried copying the files into the "htdocs" folder but it opens them up as an index and all the files open as text.

Comment: You have to run a server and route traffic to it. `rails server`, that stuff.

Comment: It's not a really good idea to open the port 80 on your home router for some security reasons. You can find very cheap vps (5$/month) or heroku and you will have a real production deployment overview. But if you still want to deploy it on your home server you have to run your rails server `rails server` and forward all the trafic on the local rails port. Default is `127.0.0.1:3000`

Comment: @Ugo Mare So, if I understand you correctly, instead of forwarding port 80 traffic to 192.168.x.x i should instead forward it to localhost:3000 and use my rails server? Sorry I am new at this. 

What precautions should I exercise with opening ports? 

What other options do I have to run http on a home server other than opening port 80?